# Divide without losing remainder

Tags: c

In C, is it possible to divide a dividend by a constant and get the result and the remainder at the same time?

I want to avoid execution of 2 division instructions, as in this example:

```
val=num / 10;
mod=num % 10;
```

Comment: If you compile this exact code with an optimizing compiler (like GCC) on x86 or x86_64, you will find it already compiles into a single `idiv` instruction.  In short, do not worry about micro-optimizations like this; at this level, modern compilers are much, much smarter than you probably think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the [`div`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/div/) function.

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't worry about the instruction count because the x86 instruction set will provide a `idivl` instruction that computes the dividend and remainder in one instruction. Any decent compiler will make use of this instruction. The documenation here http://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/2007/01/appendix-b-common-x86-instructions.html describes the instruction as follows:

> Performs unsigned division. Divides the contents of the double-word
>   contained in the combined %edx:%eax registers by the value in the
>   register or memory location specified. The %eax register contains the
>   resulting quotient, and the %edx register contains the resulting
>   remainder. If the quotient is too large to fit in %eax, it triggers a
>   type 0 interrupt.

For example, compiling this sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 39;
  int divisor = 1;
  int div = 0;
  int rem = 0;

  printf("Enter the divisor: ");
  scanf("%d", &divisor);
  div = x/divisor;
  rem = x%divisor;

  printf("div = %d, rem = %d\n", div, rem);
}
```

With gcc -S -O2 (-S saves the tempory file created that shows the asm listing), shows that the division and mod in the following lines

```
div = x/divisor;
rem = x%divisor;
```

is effectively reduced to the following instruction:

```
idivl   28(%esp)
```

As you can see theres one instruction to perform the division and mod calculation. The `idivl` instruction remains even if the mod calculation in the C program is removed. After the `idivl` there are calls to `mov`:

```
movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
call    printf
```

These calls copy the quotient and the remainder onto the stack for the call to printf.

#### Update

Interestingly the function [`div`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/div.c;h=5268f4c49440c936e23049d7eda4fde68f650369;hb=HEAD) doesn't do anything special other than wrap the / and % operators in a function call. Therefore, from a performance perspective, it will not improve the performance by replacing the lines

```
 val=num / 10;       
 mod=num % 10;
```

with a single call to `div`.

Comment: +1 for actually demonstrating that at least one compiler does it :)

Comment: While OP did want to avoid **execution** of two division instructions, I think `div()` has value for readability and maintainability. The division is done at one place in the source, not scattered at two or more places. The field names of `div_t` also make for readability, I believe.

Comment: I am genuinely confused as to why the division and modulus operations happen separately when there is a *CPU instruction* that already does it in one step.

Comment: @Sammitch I think the answer shows that they in fact *don't* happen separately. Even if you write them in two expressions, it will still compile to a single instruction. Unless you are referring to the language itself not assigning them both in the same expression. But that's a different matter.

Comment: MS Visual Studio 2017 won't use single *idiv* when pointer de-referencing like `*ptr_to_10` is used even with all optimizations enabled:(

Answer (score 6):

There's [div()](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stdlib.html#div):

```
div_t result = div(num, 10);
// quotient is result.quot
// remainder is result.rem
```

Comment: The question was more concerned about the operation count than whether you can wrap calls to % and / in a function.

Comment: @sashan: Often this type of functions are implemented as compiler intrinsics so it could have the optimal performance. Unfortunately it seems that at least in Visual c++ 10 the div call is not even inlined and it is slower than the original code.

Comment: See here: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/div.c;h=5268f4c49440c936e23049d7eda4fde68f650369;hb=HEAD. The implementation of div just wraps the calls to % and /.

Answer (score 5):

Don't waste your time with `div()` Like Nemo said, the compiler will easily optimize the use of a division followed by the use of a modulus operation into one. Write code that makes optimal sense, and let the computer remove the cruft.

Comment: Exactly, but doesn't `div()` make quite much sense as well? The `/` followed by `%` is a well-known idiom, so everybody knows what it does, but using `div()` and `div_t` does not make less sense to me. Its fields are called `quot` and `rem`, pretty self-documenting.

Comment: But using `div()` will clearly tell the compiler that you want quotient and remainder, without having to rely on the compiler being good enough to recognize that by just looking at your code. Even when the compiler won't recognize that or is very bad at optimizing code, it will surely have an highly optimized `div()` implementation for every supported platform. And as the compiler knows what `div()` does, it's part of the ISO-C standard, it usually does not even call that function but just emits the function's code.